# Declaring Function Parameters as variables

Tags: javascript, function

I am practicing functions in JavaScript where i came up with a solution for the below problem:

Write a function named tellFortune that takes 4 arguments: number of children, partner's name, geographic location, job title.
Outputs your fortune to the screen like so: "You will be a X in Y and married to Z with N kids."

**Solution:**

```
var children = N;
var partnerName = Z;
var geoLocation = Y;
var jobTitle = X;

function tellFortune(X, Y, Z, N) {
    console.log("You will be a" + X + "in" + Y + "and married to" + Z + "with" + N + "kids");
}
```

When I try to run this program I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: N is not defined'.Is my method of declaring the arguments as variables first and then calling them wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a variable `X`,`Y` or `Z`. You need to create a variable called `X` or uses `jobTitle` instead of `X` in your `console.log`.

Here is an example

```
console.log("You will be a" + jobTitle + "in" + geoLocation+ "and married to" + partnerName + "with" + children +"kids" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the variables outside of the scope of the `tellFortune` function. Have a read over [variable scoping](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) as well as this sample code and you should be able to see where you went wrong!

```
// function parameters X,Y, Z and N can't be read out here

function tellFortune(X, Y, Z, N) {
    // function parameters X,Y, Z and N can be read in here in here

    console.log("You will be a" + X + "in" + Y + "and married to" + Z + "with" + N + "kids");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine how a compiler would read your program, line by line.  When it gets to the line

```
var children = N;
```

It will assign "undefined" to children, because N is undefined (defining something is when you put "var" or "let" in front of the name).  Likewise, when you pass N into your function, N is still undefined.

If you had defined and assigned N like so, on the first line:

```
var N = 3;
```

then it would have worked.  Alternatively, you could just define children.

```
var children = 3;
```

(And the same thing goes for your other three variables--they all need to be declared and assigned a value.)

Also: you currently aren't actually calling your function yet.  You have defined how the function works, but unless you call `tellFortune()` (with defined variables passed into it) somewhere, it will not be called.

So in summary, you can change your code to this:

```
// You assign values to these variables
var children = 3;
var partnerName = "Matilda";
var geoLocation = "100,45";
var jobTitle = X;

// Now you call the function with the assigned variables passed into it
tellFortune(children , partnerName , geoLocation , jobTitle );

// The compiler will jump to this point to figure out how to execute tellFortune.  Since children was passed as the first parameter, it will be the value X in the function.  Same with partnerName being Y, etc.
function tellFortune(X, Y, Z, N) {
    // Since X Y Z and N are defined as parameters in the line before this, the compiler knows what to put in the console.log() below.
    console.log("You will be a" + X + "in" + Y + "and married to" + Z + "with" + N + "kids");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

N, Z, Y, and X are all undefined variables in your code. You were trying to tell JavaScript that the value of variable children equals the value of variable N, but you never told JavaScript what N was.

You don't need to declare those first four variables, you just need to pass whatever arguments you want when you call your function. You also have not done that. You are close, though. Delete or comment out those first four variables, call your function with whichever four strings you want below it, and see if that works.

To call a function, just write `functionName(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)`. A string is any text enclosed by "" or ''.

I would write that as a snippet, but it seems like good practice for you.